# The problem with gaps at the DOCX report: JasperReports does wrong page breaks

Tags: jasper-reports, docx

I have a problem with making report using JasperReports 4.5.1. **PDF**, **XLSX**, **RTF** formats are printing perfectly, but **DOCX** file has strange gaps sometimes. I can't track the pattern when they appear.
The report is a header on each page and the main content seems like table but it is text fields with borders.
[image]

I don't cause any page breaks on purpose. There is a part of code:
[image]

Every *textField* has property `isStretchWithOverflow=true`
Every *band* has property `splitType=prevent`

I setted properties *splitType* and *isStreatchWithOverflow* to all possible options - either it didn't help, or it got worse.

Does anyone have any thoughts?